# How can I access the static value inside Enum?

Tags: swift

I defined the following enum.
There is no rawValue and it is for convenient use of LocalizedString.

```swift
enum Localized {
  enum Str {
    static let title = NSLocalizedString("myTitle", comment: "")
    static let name = NSLocalizedString("myName", comment: "")
  }
}

// Use as follows
print(Localized.Str.title) // My Title
print(Localized.Str.name) // James
```

Can I use it by wrapping it as a function as below?
I want to make a function that receives the key as a parameter.

```swift
func convertString(with key: String) -> String {
  return Localized.Str.key // I want to do like this.
}

// Can I use it as below?
print(convertString(with: "title")) // My Title
print(convertString(with: "name")) // James
```

```swift
// Localized File
"myTitle" = "My Title";
"myName" = "James";
```

Comment: Why don't you use `Localized.Str.title` instead of `"title"`.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez This question assumes that enum cannot be modified.

Comment: It's very unclear what you want and the comment you posted three times doesn't do anything to clarify. You're not even using enum cases. I'm voting to close this question.

Answer (score 1):

You can change you code a little bit:

```
enum Str: String {
    // Your cases
    case title = "myTitle"
    case name = "myName"
   // Create computed property or function
   var localized: Sting {
       NSLocalizedString(self.rawValue, comment: "")
   }
}
```

And you can use it like this:

```
Str.name.localized
```

Comment: This question assumes that enum cannot be modified.

Answer (score 1):

Would this be more ergonomic?

```
enum Strings: String, CustomStringConvertible {
    case title = "myTitle"
    case name = "myName"
        
    var description: String {
        NSLocalizedString(rawValue, comment: "")
    }
}
```

Comment: This question assumes that enum cannot be modified.